# What can I use as an alternative to the readAsDataURL method to get a base64 encoded data url

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Phonegap app and it records audio and uploads the audio to my server. The code below allows for me to read the recorded audio file and return data as a base64 encoded data url using the [readAsDataURL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) method and then display the url in an alert box. The code works perfectly on Android but not on ios. The documentation says in regard to ios: "iOS Quirks encoding parameter is not supported, UTF8 encoding is always used."
so I was wondering if anyone could provide me with an alternative. I just would like the end result to be the same result I get on Android, an alert box displaying the data url. I understand the alert box may not display the entire url. I only am using the alert box for confirmation. I want my variable to have the data url stored in it.

My Code:

```
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getFile("myaudio.wav", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
readDataUrl(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("Read as data URL");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
    var theFile = evt.target.result;
    alert(theFile); //shows data url on Android
};
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, function fail(){});
```

Comment: audioTag.src=URL.createObjectURL(file);

Comment: Thank you, I'm a little confused on how use that. Can you explain further?